# I cannot find rather popular code (and maybe text) editor

Tags: text-editor, code-editor

I've seen text/code editors like this a lot of times, but I still didn't find what's the text/code editor is this? Can you help me?
[This is that text/code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm5Kw.jpg)

Hope I'll get **answer with no aggressive things)**

Comment: So the IDE’s that I know of that support Unity are Rider, VisualStudio and VisualStudioCode. Unfortunately, your image quality is pretty poor and that could literally be a notepad instance

Comment: The quality is bad, 'cause it's from video, and it's small part in the video

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) with a **light theme** considering there is Unity code and the indentation level is represented by dots rather than solid lines.

Comment: I tried, looks pretty cool. But it's Notepad++

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).